# How can I get a list of objects that appeared newly in an image with OpenCv?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to identify a list of objects that appeared newly in a photo. The plan is to get multiple cropped images from the original image and feed them to a neural network for object detection. Right now, I'm having trouble in extracting objects that appeared in a frame.

```
import cv2 as cv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def mdisp(image):
    plt.imshow(image)
    plt.show()

im1 = cv.imread('images/litter-before.jpg')
mdisp(im1)
print(im1.shape)
im2 = cv.imread('images/litter-after.jpg')
mdisp(im2)
print(im2.shape)
backsub1=cv.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()
backsub2=cv.createBackgroundSubtractorKNN()
fgmask = backsub1.apply(im1)
fgmask = backsub1.apply(im2)
print(fgmask.shape)
mdisp(fgmask)
new_image = im2 * (fgmask[:,:,None].astype(im2.dtype))
mdisp(new_image)
```

[image: litter-before.jpg]
[image: litter-after.jpg]
[image: mask and join]

Ideally, I would like to get a cropped picture of the item within red circle. How can I do it with OpenCv

[image]
[image]

Comment: Provide clean input images please

Comment: the image was captured using https://motion-project.github.io in raspberry pi. I tried to increase the quality, but it didn't improve much. I do see the difference with current image, can we draw a rectangle around that?

Comment: Provide the files `litter-before.jpg` and `litter-after.jpg` so it is possible for other people to debug your code.

Comment: uploaded original files litter-before.jpg and litter-after.jpg that I used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach, subtracting the two frames directly. The idea is that you first convert your images to `grayscale`, then `blur` a little bit to ignore the noise. `Subtract` the two frames, `threshold` the difference and look for the **largest** blob that is above a certain area threshold value.

Let's see:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# image path
path = "C:/opencvImages/"
fileName01 = "01.jpg"
fileName02 = "02.jpg"

# Read the2 images in default mode:
image01 = cv2.imread(path + fileName01)
image02 = cv2.imread(path + fileName02)

# Store a copy of the last frame for results drawing:
inputCopy = image02.copy()

# Convert RGB images to grayscale:
grayscaleImage01 = cv2.cvtColor(image01, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
grayscaleImage02 = cv2.cvtColor(image02, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Convert RGB images to grayscale:
filterSize = 5
imageMedian01 = cv2.medianBlur(grayscaleImage01, filterSize)
imageMedian02 = cv2.medianBlur(grayscaleImage02, filterSize)
```

Now you have the grayscale, blurred frames. Next, we need to calculate the difference between these frames. I don't wanna loose data, so I have to be careful with the data type here. Remember that these are grayscale, `uint8` matrices, but the difference could potentially yield negative values. Let's convert the matrices to `float`s, take the difference, and convert this matrix to uint8:

```
# uint8 to float32 conversion:
imageMedian01 = imageMedian01.astype('float32')
imageMedian02 = imageMedian02.astype('float32')

# Take the difference and convert back to uint8
imageDifference = np.clip(imageMedian01 - imageMedian02, 0, 255)
imageDifference = imageDifference.astype('uint8')
```

This gives you the frames difference:

[image]

Let's threshold this to get a binary image. I'm using a threshold value of `127`, as it is a the center of the 8-bit range:

```
threshValue = 127
_, binaryImage = cv2.threshold(imageDifference, threshValue, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

This is the binary image:

[image]

We are looking for the biggest blob here, let's find `blob/contours` and filter the small ones. Let's set a minimum area of 10 pixels:

```
# Perform an area filter on the binary blobs:
componentsNumber, labeledImage, componentStats, componentCentroids = \
    cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(binaryImage, connectivity=4)

# Set the minimum pixels for the area filter:
minArea = 10

# Get the indices/labels of the remaining components based on the area stat
# (skip the background component at index 0)
remainingComponentLabels = [i for i in range(1, componentsNumber) if componentStats[i][4] >= minArea]

# Filter the labeled pixels based on the remaining labels,
# assign pixel intensity to 255 (uint8) for the remaining pixels
filteredImage = np.where(np.isin(labeledImage, remainingComponentLabels) == True, 255, 0).astype('uint8')

# Find the big contours/blobs on the filtered image:
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(filteredImage, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

contours_poly = [None] * len(contours)
boundRect = []

# Alright, just look for the outer bounding boxes:
for i, c in enumerate(contours):
    if hierarchy[0][i][3] == -1:
        contours_poly[i] = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 3, True)
        boundRect.append(cv2.boundingRect(contours_poly[i]))


# Draw the bounding boxes on the (copied) input image:
for i in range(len(boundRect)):
    print(boundRect[i])
    color = (0, 255, 0)
    cv2.rectangle(inputCopy, (int(boundRect[i][0]), int(boundRect[i][1])), \
                  (int(boundRect[i][0] + boundRect[i][2]), int(boundRect[i][1] + boundRect[i][3])), color, 1)
```

Check out the results:

[image]

Comment: thanks!! exactly what I was looking for. I made a couple of changes to increase the box area and added one more variable for find contours return `img, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours`

Comment: @Ravi no problem, my friend. Glad I could help.